# Subquotients of representations and character

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a group, $K$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $\rho_1,\rho_2:G\to \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ be two semi-simple representations. What I would like to be able to determine is if $\rho_1$ is a subquotient of $\rho_2$. Since the character determines the isomorphism-classes of representations uniquely, and being a subquotient is independent of the choice of isomorphism-class, I would like to know if I can determine/test "being a subquotient" via the character?

That is to say, is there a partial ordering $\leq$ on functions $G\to K$ such that
$$\rho_1\leq \rho_2 \iff \chi_{\rho_1}\leq \chi_{\rho_2}.$$

Comment: There is a reductive algebraic group scheme $H$ over $K$ and a homomorphism $G\to H$, such that every semi-simple representation of $G$ factors through $H$. Your question has a positive answer for representations of $H$, so *theoretically* there is such a partial order.

Comment: @Kapil How can we read of "being a subquotient" of the character for reductive algebraic groups? Also, do you happen to know a reference for the existence of $H$?

Comment: The standard representation theory for reductive groups (see e.g. the book of Springer in Linear Algebraic Groups) should give the answer to the first question. About the existence of $H$, the basic result is that if $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}_n$ is a semi-simple representation, then the Zariski closure of the image is a reductive group. Now one has to take a projective limit of such images to get $H$.

Comment: If G is very large (e.g. an uncountable free group), then H constructed as this projective limit will be too large to be of finite type.